# Android - Making SoundPool a global class? (Available to all other classes)

Tags: android, global-variables, soundpool

So basically, I'm creating a game on a SurfaceView and I have these classes on my main CustomView:

```
private TitleScreen titleScreen;
private GameScreen gameScreen;
private PauseScreen pauseScreen;
private GameOverScreen gameOverScreen;
```

Each of these classes have a `draw(Canvas canvas)` method, and is called when the user goes to another screen. But the thing is, I have a `SoundPlayer` class that includes all of my sound effects using SoundPool. It will be used on all these classes. Is there actually a way that the SoundPlayer only loads once, then is available throughout these classes? Or do I have to call `release()` and recall the constructor everytime I switch? Thanks in advance. :D

UPDATE (SOLVED):

So here's what I did. I created an instance of my SoundPlayer class:

```
public class SoundPlayerInstance {
    private static SoundPlayer soundPlayerInstance;
    private SoundPlayerInstance(){}

    public static void createInstance(Context context){
        soundPlayerInstance = new SoundPlayer(context);
    }

    public static SoundPlayer getInstance(){
        return soundPlayerInstance;
    }
}
```

On my main view, before I do anything, I call this in my constructor:

`SoundPlayerInstance.createInstance();`

Then, on any of my classes, I can just call it to play the sound:

`SoundPlayerInstance.getInstance().playSound();`

I think this will be useful not only for situations like these, but it can also be useful for developers (like me) that want to instantiate a class that is available throughout all other classes. Thanks to system32 for answering my question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there actually a way that the SoundPlayer only loads once, then is
>   available throughout these classes?

It's possible. Make `SoundPlayer` class singleton.

```
public class SoundPlayer
{

  private static SoundPlayer instance;

  private SoundPlayer()
  {
     // Do some stuff
  }

  public static SoundPlayer getInstance()
  {
     if(instance == null)
         instance = new SoundPlayer();

     return instance;
  }

}
```

To access globally, just call `SoundPlayer.getInstance()`

Comment: Do I create this class in my main CustomView? I'll have a go at this and see if it works. Thanks. :)

Comment: You have a `SoundPlayer` class right? just modify it. That's a good way to load resources/objects once :)

Comment: It's totally working now. I just edited your code a bit. thanks. :D

Comment: But which context can you use to load sounds into the singleton hashmap? Using this without passing a context gives me an error involving problems about enclosing class. Creating the singleton by passing a context gives me a problem when my game is moved away from, the soundpool is unloaded and I return, because the activity I return to doesn't load the singleton. The only thing I could think of would be to try and restart (and reload the sounds) the singleton on every activity I start...maybe using getBaseContext().

Comment: @MacD Use `getApplicationContext()` it's a singleton context

Comment: Thanks...that's exactly what I did :) Although it did suck to have to add that initialisation to each and every activity's onResume!